# Spring/Tomcat/Jetty: Creating new class causes "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" although the class exists and other classes are working

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, jetty, classnotfoundexception

I'm dealing with this problem the whole last week: 
I've created a new class (af.backend.service.InitService2), defined it in "spring-configuration.xml", tried to start my webapplication and got (and still getting) this exception:

Tomcat:

```
Aug 04, 2014 12:59:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [af.backend.service.InitService2] for bean with name 'initService' defined in class path resource [spring-configuration.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: af.backend.service.InitService2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
```

Jetty:

```
2014-08-04 00:59:19.262:WARN::Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [af.backend.service.InitService2] for bean with name 'initService' defined in class path resource [spring-configuration.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: af.backend.service.InitService2:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: af.backend.service.InitService2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:392)
    at runjettyrun.ProjectClassLoader.loadClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:89)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1242)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:97)
```

The "funny" thing is that there are already other beans in the same package, which are working fine and the InitService2.class-file is present in the target folder (\target\classes\af\backend\services - as the other working ones)

spring-configuration.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="genericDao" class="af.backend.services.GenericDaoImpl" autowire="constructor" />

    <bean id="initService" class="af.backend.service.InitService2" >
    </bean>


    <bean id="configurationService" class="af.backend.services.ConfigurationServiceImpl">
        <constructor-arg ref="genericDao"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="roleService" class="af.backend.services.RoleServiceImpl" autowire="constructor" />
    <bean id="userFacade" class="af.backend.services.UserServiceImpl" autowire="constructor" />
    <bean id="loginFacade" class="af.backend.services.LoginServiceImpl" autowire="constructor" />

    <bean id="streamService" class="af.backend.services.StreamServiceImpl">
        <constructor-arg ref="configurationService"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="shoutboxService" class="af.backend.services.ShoutboxServiceImpl">
        <constructor-arg ref="configurationService"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg ref="genericDao"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="newsService" class="af.backend.services.NewsServiceImpl">
        <constructor-arg ref="configurationService"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg ref="genericDao"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl" class="af.backend.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />
    <bean id="sessionRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

</beans>
```

Only "initService" is causing problems. All other beans are working fine.
The only thing i've done before creating a new bean was refactoring the already working beans by extracting interfaces of them...maybe thats root cause??

Using:

- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
  Version: Kepler Service Release 1
  Build id: 20130919-0819

  - Spring: 3.0.5.RELEASE
  - Maven: 2.3.2
  - Tomcat: 7.0
  - Jetty: 6.1.26

Comment: How do you run your web application: inside eclipse IDE or do you deploy your application to a separate Server-Instance.

Comment: Moreover if you run the application, have you checked that the class is packaged in the resulting war?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I run my web application inside Eclipse. But the same error occurrs if i create a war file via command line and deploying it on a sepereate server.

Comment: How do you assemble your war? Have you double-checked the war and the jars by unzipping the war-package and your jars?

Comment: I found the problem/solution: 
I misspelled the class in spring-configuration.xml. Should be "af.backend.services.InitService2" instead of "af.backend.service.InitService2"...the 's' was missing. (Although that was my first idea and i checked that twice - shame on me -.-)